# Chrome for Android freezes the tab after 5 minutes of inactivity (chrome v 94)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket, progressive-web-apps

My app includes the websocket, that should work continuously. However, if tab isn't active for more than 5 minutes, the ping message from my client don't send anymore, and connection closes as result.

I've read advices such as changing some settings in chrome://flags (e.g. 'Tab Freeze' or 'Calculate window occlusion'), but as for 'Tab freeze' - it looks like it's already released feature that set by default, and now it's not listed at chrome://flags anymore.
And as for 'Calculate window occlusion' - it works only for Windows.
Another advice that i find was related to chrome://discards, but this link doesn't open on Chrome for Android.

Is there any way to prevent chrome of freezing tabs and make tab's work stable?

Comment: Did you get a way around it ?

Comment: Looks like an architecture refactoring is on the cards for your app.